# How to verify Why3 output of Proof Obligations

Tags: frama-c, why3

I believe I can generate proofs using why3 with different provers,

1. `frama-c -wp -wp-prover cvc4 -wp-rte -wp-out proof swap.c`
2. `frama-c -wp -wp-prover z3-ce -wp-rte -wp-out proof swap.c`
3. `frama-c -wp -wp-prover alt-ergo -wp-rte -wp-out proof swap.c`

This generates different 'why' files.  I would like to validate the proof obligations with an external program.  It seems each proof obligation is in a different format; <strike>Lisp</strike>Clojure and OCaml?  What exactly is the format? Is it correct that these are proof and are sufficient to show the contract/proof is correct without proving that Z3, alt-ergo, etc are correct?

#### swap.c

For the [wp tutorial](https://allan-blanchard.fr/publis/frama-c-wp-tutorial-en.pdf),

```
int h = 42;
/*@
  requires \valid(a) && \valid(b);
  assigns *a, *b;
  ensures *a == \old(*b) && *b == \old(*a);
*/
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 24;
    int b = 37;

    //@ assert h == 42;

    swap(&a, &b);

    //@ assert a == 37 && b == 24;
    //@ assert h == 42;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine and the *frama-c-gui* shows me how to develop contracts and annotations.

#### Alter-ergo

```
(* WP Task for Prover Alt-Ergo,2.4.1 *) (* this is the prelude for Alt-Ergo, version >= 2.4.0 *) (* this is a prelude for Alt-Ergo integer arithmetic *) (* this is a prelude for Alt-Ergo real arithmetic *) type string

logic match_bool : bool, 'a, 'a -> 'a

axiom match_bool_True :   (forall z:'a. forall z1:'a. (match_bool(true, z, z1) = z))
```

The full proof is truncated for brevity.

#### z3-ce

```
(* WP Task for Prover Z3,4.8.11,counterexamples *) ;;; generated by SMT-LIB2 driver ;;; SMT-LIB2 driver: bit-vectors, common part ;;; generated by SMT-LIB strings ;;; generated by SMT-LIB strings (set-option :produce-models true) ;;; SMT-LIB2: integer arithmetic ;;; SMT-LIB2: real arithmetic (declare-sort uni 0)

(declare-sort ty 0)

(declare-fun sort (ty uni) Bool)

(declare-fun witness (ty) uni)
```

The full proof is truncated for brevity.

Comment: ZMT-LIB is found at the URL http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/.  It looks like both Z3 and CVC4 use this format as output.  Still not sure about Alt-Ergo.

Comment: Removing the first line `(* WP Task for Prover...)` and I can use `cvc4 --lang smt2 file.why` and `z3 -smt2 file.why` process the files, where 'file.why' was produced with that prover.  I can not verify z3 output with cvc4, for instance... [smtlib grammar in flex/bison](https://es-static.fbk.eu/people/griggio/misc/smtlib2parser.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that I'm not completely sure that I completely understand what you want to achieve here, but here are the answers to your questions:

> It seems each proof obligation is in a different format; Lisp and OCaml? What exactly is the format?

These files represent the formulas that are given to the provers you ask Frama-C to launch. The format depends on the prover. If I recall correctly, for many provers, this will be [smtlib](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/),  or [tptp](http://www.tptp.org/TPTP/QuickGuide/), but some provers such as Alt-Ergo can also enjoy a custom output. The generation of the file is described by Why3's driver files, as mentioned (quite briefly) in section 12.4 of the [Why3 manual](http://why3.lri.fr/doc/technical.html#drivers-for-external-provers).

> Is it correct that these are proof ?

No, these are formulas to be validated by the prover they have been generated for.

> and are sufficient to show the contract/proof is correct without proving that Z3, alt-ergo, etc are correct?

No. If the provers you use have a bug, they might mistakenly tell you that a given proof obligation is valid. Some provers are able to provide a proof trace (e.g. if you tweak a driver to use the `get-proof` command of smtlib), but as far as I know, the format of such a trace is prover-specific, so that it would probably be difficult to have it checked by an external tool.

Comment: So just to clarify the proof obligation is an internal format for the prover.  I was hoping for an existence of a file which could be independently verified.  This is the essence of a  mathematical proof.  Any one can verify it is true by different means even if the mechanics of how the proof was created is unknown.  It is a mechanism used by 'proof carrying code' (only a verification needs to be provided on a device), but I was just interested in external verification of the proofs.

Comment: I suppose that using multiple proofs achieves the same goal to show the annotation and code satisfy each other.  Ie, multiple provers show the code and contract/annotations are correct.  Although I guess in some situations, one prover maybe able to produce a result and another would not.  It seems simpler just to verify a produced proof.

Comment: you might be interested by Dedukti  (https://deducteam.github.io/), which aims at providing a unified framework for checking proofs. However, I'm not sure whether the tools that can output dedukti proofs can be readily used as Why3 back ends.

Comment: [drat-trim](https://github.com/marijnheule/drat-trim), [Springer article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10817-019-09525-z)... those are for SAT solvers, not SMT.